# CSV to SQL - Add 1 day to a Date in a datacolumn

Tags: c#, csv, datetime, sqlbulkcopy, datacolumn

I am trying to add 1 day to all dates that are in a certain datacolumn ['RecordAddedDate']

```
csvData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] {                     
new DataColumn("Manufacturer", typeof(string)),
new DataColumn("SupplierCode", typeof(string)),
new DataColumn("RecordAddedDate", typeof(DateTime))});
```

At the moment the moment I have this working:

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < csvData.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(fieldData[2]);
var newDate = dt2.AddDays(1);
csvData.Rows[rowIndex][2] = newDate;                                    
}
```

But it only adds 1 day to the first row read from the csv and doesn't add for the rest.

Any Help?

Here is the while loop which reads the data from the csv and adds the data

```
 while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
                {
                    string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();
                    //Making empty value as null
                    for (int i = 0; i < fieldData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(fieldData[i]);
                        if (fieldData[i] == "")
                        {
                            fieldData[i] = null;
                        }

                        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < csvData.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
                        {
                            DateTime dt2 = csvData.Rows[rowIndex].Field<DateTime>(2);
                            DateTime newDate = dt2.AddDays(1);
                            csvData.Rows[rowIndex][2] = newDate;
                        }                             

                    }
                    csvData.Rows.Add(fieldData);
                    Console.WriteLine("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);
                }
            }
        return csvData;
```

Comment: What is `fieldData` here? Shouldn't you be starting with `csvData.Rows[rowIndex][2]`?

Comment: csvData is the DataTable. I edited the row index now to a smaller int as its a large table and I didnt want to add it all in this post.

Comment: Why not use SSIS for moving the data from CSV to Excel? It supports import from Excel and custom actions if required.

Comment: I didn't ask about `csvData` - that seems reasonably obvious. I asked about `fieldData`, which is what you're using to get the initial value. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: Sorry I missed read. fieldData is the row data being entered into the array from the csv. I have also updated my original post.

Answer (score 0):

What is `fieldData[2]`? You are always using this in the loop, so no wonder that you always get the same `DateTime`. If the table is already filled and you want to update a value use `csvData.Rows[rowIndex][2] = csvData.Rows[rowIndex].Field<DateTime>(2).AddDays(1);`

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < csvData.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
{
    DateTime dt2 = csvData.Rows[rowIndex].Field<DateTime>(2);
    DateTime newDate = dt2.AddDays(1);
    csvData.Rows[rowIndex][2] = newDate;                                    
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately it still only adds 1 day to the "RecordAddedDate" to the 1st row only and not the rest. Should this be in a while loop you think?

Comment: @TeaAnyOne: that can only be if the table contains only one row. A for-loop is perfect for this task.

Comment: Im 100% there is 2 rows. as I receive 2 from `Console.WriteLine("Rows count:" + csvData.Rows.Count);` ------ Is this the issue? `DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(fieldData[2]);` I believe that `fieldData[2]` only references the first row value and not the 2nd row value. Is there anyway to reference and parse a column of data?

Comment: @TeaAnyOne: What is `fieldData` at all? However, it will never change, i have mentioned  that in my answer. Why haven't you used my code? It seems that you have simply ignored my answer. Use `csvData.Rows[rowIndex].Field<DateTime>(2)` to get the `RecordAddedDate` of each row. Then add one day and write it back to the cell value.